# how to send headers on Lua script?

Tags: lua, http-get

Hi I want to send headers in lua.

I write code like this

```
local response = http.get(url,{headers:{'x-api-key':MY API KEY}})
```

but I got  expected near '{' message.

how to I send header on lua script? plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

> but I got expected near '{' message.

This is a clear syntax error. You should be able to fix these yourself after googling for them, consulting the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.9). Your editor highlighting syntax errors is also useful; linters like [luacheck](https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck) provide this.

The reason is that Lua does not use `:` (like JS or JSON) but `=` for delimiting key-value pairs; key-value pairs are written as `[key] = value`, with the special exception that keys which are identifiers / "names" (could be used as variable names) can conveniently be written as `name = value`. This allows us to write `headers = {...}`. `['x-api-key'] = ...` can't be shortened this way because hyphens aren't allowed in variable names in Lua.

Replace your code with the following line:

```lua
local response = http.get(url,{headers = {['x-api-key'] = MY API KEY}})
```

to fix the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! LMD >< Unfortunately, I tried it before but I got 'api key required' message... I

Comment: local response = http.get(url,{header = {['x-api-key'] = MY API KEY}})

is working